# The sign in option won't disappear after signing in VSCODE

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension and trying to create my own Authentication Provider. I've noticed that the 'sign in' option doesn't disappear even after I've already signed in. I have to reopen Visual Studio Code to get rid of it.
Does anyone know the reason behind this and how to fix it?

[image]